# Converting a lowercase char to uppercase without using an if statement

Tags: java, char, case-conversion

How I can convert a lowercase `char` to uppercase without using an if statement?. I.e. don't use code like this:

```
if(c > 'a' && c < 'z')
{
    c = c-32;
}
```

Comment: Look into the `Character` class methods.

Comment: You can't just use [toUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29)?

Comment: @Gray just so you know, that documentation is two major versions and over 2.5 years out of date.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Thanks, I didn't notice. I just googled Character touppercase and picked the first one.

Comment: Brand new version: [toUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that your characters are ASCII alphabetic, then you can unset the bit that makes it lowercase, since the difference between the lowercase and uppercase latin chars is only one bit in the ASCII table.

You can simply do:

```
char upper = c & 0x5F;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
char uppercase = Character.toUpperCase(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Character.toUpperCase(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-):

> Converts the character argument to uppercase using case mapping information from the UnicodeData file.

For example, `Character.toUpperCase('a')` returns `'A'`.

So the full code you probably want is:

```
c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
```

Comment: thanks,I understand this uppercase ,but i don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java). For your case, try something like this:

```
c = (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ? c = c - 32 : c;
```

Comment: you'd probably want to make the else section of the ternary return c instead of 1 though.

Comment: Also, why are you assigning `c` to the whole expression, but assigning `c` in the middle of it also?  That's a construction that is horrible and may actually break in some non-Java languages where evaluation of order is less well-defined.